# Libnotify delays after upgrade to 13.10

Tags: 13.10, libnotify

After upgrade to 13.10 libnotify started to behave strangely - notifications come with delay. For example, I receive mail, Thunderbird plays notification and only after some time (5-10 seconds maybe) OSD shows and message indicator (or whatever it is?) turns blue. Same for pidgin.